# Exercise 11 page 179 of Hungerford's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, modules, exact-sequence

Following are items (e) and (f) of Exercise 11 page 179 of Hungerford's Algebra: [ the set T(A) is all torsion elements of A]

> (e) If $0 \to A \to B \to C$ is an exact sequence of R-modules, then so is
> $0 \to T(A) \to T(B) \to T(C)$
> (f) If $g :B \to C$ is an R-module epimorphism, then $g_T : T(B) \to T(C)$ need not be an epimorphism. [Hint: consider abelian groups.]

For (e) : $Ker(g)=Im(f)$. If $x \in Ker(g_T)$ then g_T(x)=0. Because $T(B) \subset$ B then $x \in Ker(g)=Im(f)$. Thus $x \in =Im(f_T)$. I cannot go the other direction because it seems not obvious how $x \in =Im(f)$ implies $x \in =Im(f_T)$ to proceed the rest.

For (f) : We need to find an element in T(C) which is not in $g_T(T(C))$. I don't know how and the hint seems not relevant?

Answer (score 2):

This is exercise 11 on page 179 of Hungerford's Algebra book.

Let us recall the initial items that we are going to use.

From (a), we know that, if $A$ is a module over a commutative ring $R$, then
$T(A) =\{a \in A | \text{ exists } r\in R, r \neq 0 \text{ and } ra=0 \}$.

From (b), we know that, if $R$ is an integral domain, then $T(A)$ is a submodule of $A$.

For item (d) to (f) $R$ is an integral domain.

From (d) we know that, if $f: A \to B$ is an $R$-module homomorphism, then $f(T(A)) \subseteq T(B)$; hence the restriction $f_T$ of $f$ to $T(A)$ ia an $R$-module homomorphism $T(A) \to T(B)$.

Now let us solve items (e) and (f).

**Item (e)**: Suppose $0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C$ is an exact sequence.

Step 1: From item(d), we have that $f_T:T(A) \to T(B)$ and $g_T:T(B) \to T(C)$ are $R$-modules homomorphism.

Step 2: Since $0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C$ is an exact sequence, we have that $f$ is a monomorphism, so $f_T$ (the restriction of $f$ to the submodule $T(A)$) is also a monomorphism.

Step 3:  Since $0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C$ is an exact sequence, we have that $\mathrm{Im}(f) = \mathrm{Ker}(g)$. Since $f_T$ is a restriction of $f$, we have  $\mathrm{Im}(f_T) \subseteq  \mathrm{Ker}(g)$, and since $\mathrm{Im}(f_T) \subseteq  T(B)$. We have that $\mathrm{Im}(f_T) \subseteq  \mathrm{Ker}(g) \cap T(B)= \mathrm{Ker}(g_T)$. So, we have proved that   $\mathrm{Im}(f_T) \subseteq  \mathrm{Ker}(g_T)$. Let us prove that the equality holds.

Given any $b \in \mathrm{Ker}(g_T)$. It means that $b \in T(B) \subseteq B$ such that $g_T(b) =0$. Since $g_T$ is a restriction of $g$, we have $g(b)=0$. So $b \in \mathrm{Ker}(g)$. Since  $\mathrm{Im}(f) = \mathrm{Ker}(g)$, there is $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Since $b \in T(B)$, there is $r \in R$, $r\neq 0$ such that $rb=0$. So, $f(ra)= rf(a)=rb=0$. So $ra \in \mathrm{Ker}(f)$. But, $f$ is a monomorphism, so $ra=0$, so $a\in T(A)$.  So, we have $f_T(a) =f(a)=b$. It means $b \in  \mathrm{Im}(f_T)$. So, we have proved $\mathrm{Im}(f_T) \subseteq  \mathrm{Ker}(g_T)$.

From steps 1, 2 and 3 above, we have that
$0 \to T(A) \xrightarrow{f_T} T(B) \xrightarrow{g_T} T(C)$ is an exact sequence.

**item (f)**: Consider $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z /4\Bbb Z$ as $\Bbb Z$-modules.
Note that $\Bbb Z$ is an integral domain.

Let $g: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z /4\Bbb Z$ defined by $g(n) = n \bmod 4$. It is easy to prove that $g$ is a $\Bbb Z$-module epimorphism.

On the other hand, $T(\Bbb Z) =\{0\}$ and $T(\Bbb Z /4\Bbb Z) =\{\overline{0},\overline{2}\}$. So $g_T$ can not be an epimorphism.

Comment: Another easy way to show $\subseteq$ in step 3 is that $$g\circ f=0 \text{ (by exactness at $B$)} \implies g_T\circ f_T=0 \implies \text{Im }f_T \subseteq \text{Ker } g_T.$$

Comment: @user264745 If we work the details of your argument, we have:  
$g\circ f=0 \text{ (by exactness at $B$)} \implies g|_{\text{Im }f_T}\circ f_T=0$. Then, since that $\text{Im }f_T \subseteq T(B)=\text{Dom }g_T$, we have $g_T\circ f_T=0 $. This is essentially the same kind of argument that I used in the answer.

Comment: Let $a\in T(A)$. Then $g_T\circ f_T(a)=g_T(f_T(a))=g_T(f(a))=g(f(a))=0$. Thus $g_T\circ f_T=0$.

Comment: Again, if you work the details: for $g_T\circ f_T(a)$ being well-defined,  you need to use / prove that $\text{Im }f_T \subseteq T(B)=\text{Dom }g_T$. This is essentially the same kind of argument that I used in the answer.

Comment: In hindsight, I should have mentioned what I mean by “Another easy way”. I meant different way of presentation but details is same.

Answer (score 0):

$ker(f_T)\subseteq ker(f)\Rightarrow f_T$ is injective.

$f_T(A)=f(T(A))\subseteq ker(g)\bigcap T(B)=ker(g_T)$ and $ker(g_T)=ket(g)\bigcap T(B)=f(A)\bigcap T(B)\subseteq f(T(A))=f_T(A)$ since $b\in f(A)\bigcap T(B)\Rightarrow b=f(a)$ and $rb=0$ for some $a\in A$ and $r\in R-\{0\}\Rightarrow f(ra)=rf(a)=rb=0\Rightarrow ra\in ker(f)=\{0\}\Rightarrow a\in T(A)\Rightarrow b=f(a)\in f(T(A))$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).